# Finding mesh block number using coordinates R

Tags: r, geospatial

I am trying to find the meshblock number (MeshblockN) for provided coordinates. So I have two datasets. 1. Dataset A with unique-id and co-ordinates. 2. shape file with mesh block number and other details - Dataset B.

What I have done so far, loaded the shape file - dataset B in to R using `readOGR()` function. And loaded the dataset A which has lat and long. Then applied coordinates() function to dataset A. Now I have the two required inputs for `pts.poly <- point.in.poly(A,B)`. But I am getting this error -

```
Error in data.frame(z@data, stats::na.omit(sp::over(pts, polys))) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

> head(A@data)
  row_names unique_id
1         1    2837061
> head(A@coords)
  longitude  latitude
1  170.5065 -45.86696

> head(B@data, n = 1)
   Meshblock MeshblockN AreaUnitCo AreaUnitNa      
0 MB 0352700    0352700     510402    Chelsea  



 > head(B@polygons, n = 1)
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 174.72094 -36.82045

Slot "area":
[1] 2.858646e-05

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           [,1]      [,2]
  [1,] 174.7181 -36.81820
  [2,] 174.7184 -36.81831
  [3,] 174.7188 -36.81824
  .
  .
[500,] 174.7241 -36.82205
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 363 rows ]



Slot "plotOrder":
[1] 1

Slot "labpt":
[1] 174.72094 -36.82045

Slot "ID":
[1] "0"

Slot "area":
[1] 2.858646e-05
```

Can anyone help me to proceed? Not sure whats wrong on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered this so far, I am updating my own version, I solved it using over function in sp package. `over(A,B)`